# Python: Calculating GTIN-8 Number, code works but sometimes returns negative barcode numbers

Tags: python, barcode

The program is gets an input of 7 digits from an 8 digit GTIN8(barcode) number, multiplies them alternately by 3 and 1, then subtracts the sum of that from the sum's nearest multiple of 10.

The Code works, but sometimes returns a negative number from the algorithm, but shouldn't.

Here is the Code:

```
GTIN=(input("Enter a 7 digit GTIN number: "))
length=len(GTIN)
if(length==7):
  P1=int(GTIN[0])
P2=int(GTIN[1])
P3=int(GTIN[2])
P4=int(GTIN[3])
P5=int(GTIN[4])
P6=int(GTIN[5])
P7=int(GTIN[6])
GTINT=int(P1*3+P2+P3*3+P4+P5*3+P6+P7*3)
roundup=round(GTINT, -1)
GTIN8=int(roundup-GTINT)
print("Your full GTIN-8 code is: "+str(GTIN)+str(GTIN8))
```

Here is what happens when it works:

Enter a 7 digit GTIN number: 9638507
Your full GTIN-8 code is: 96385074

As you can see, the returned number is not a negative number.

Here is what happens when it doesn't work:

Enter a 7 digit GTIN number: 5701234
Your full GTIN-8 code is: 5701234-4

A negative number is returned, which it should not. Any ideas for why?

Comment: Matey, just so you know, in your fourth to last line the variable name has been entered incorrectly. You wrote GTINT instead of GTIN. Your welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

The check digit algorithm on UPC/GTIN can produce negative numbers, which you should convert to positive using [MOD 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Trade_Item_Number). Change your last line from:

```
GTIN8=int(roundup-GTINT)
```

to

```
GTIN8 = int(roundup - GTINT) % 10
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!